# Sublime Text 2/3 change snippets folder

Tags: sublime-text-2, sublime-text-3

Is there a way to change the folder of user snippets? By default it's something like: `C:\Users\AwesomeUser\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User`

And I would like to have my snippets in, for example, `D:\_MyProject`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are Mac OS, you can use a symlink (https://gigaom.com/2011/04/27/how-to-create-and-use-symlinks-on-a-mac/) to your other folder:

```
ln -s ~/Documents/_MyProject ~/Library/Application\ Support/Sublime\ Text\ 3/Packages/User/Snippets
```

Answer (score 0):

You [can run Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/command-line) from the command line with the `--data [DIRECTORY]` argument to specify a custom application data folder.

Comment: That won't work, I just want this exactly one folder _linked_.